# How can I construct a path to the cache directory on iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, cocoa

I have what feels like the wrong way to construct a path to the cache directory on iOS...

```
- (NSString*)pathToCachesDirectory {
    NSString *cachesDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, 
                                     NSUserDomainMask, 
                                     YES) lastObject];

    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@/%@.%@",
                              cachesDirectory,
                              kDirectory,
                              kFileName,
                              kFileExtension];
}
```

Using `stringWithFormat` just feels hacky, what's the proper way to construct a file path on iOS, given the directory, file name, and file extension of that file?

Thanks in advance for your wisdom!

Comment: The setting of `cachesDirectory` is correct. Do as omz states in his answer instead of `stringWithFormat`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `stringByAppendingPathComponent:` and `stringByAppendingPathExtension:` methods.